# Use Button onClick() with controller in VR in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, user-interface, button, uibutton, virtual-reality

I am trying to access a button on the UI and use the onClick() event with a button of my VR controller (primary button). After the button is pressed I want to call a method. Now how do I do this with a controller and not with a click with the mouse? I hope you can help me out.

Kind regards

Comment: You need to raycast when the controller button is pressed and detect the collision on the canvas elements. There are a few ways for that. Manually, using the XR Interaction Toolkit, and the XR Ray Interactor. This guy explains it well https://sneakydaggergames.medium.com/vr-in-unity-navigate-ui-elements-with-the-ray-interactor-fbd010980573

Comment: Thanks for answering!
The problem is that I don't wanna "aim" at the button. I just want to do it like in a simple 2D game. The button is tracked by my hand and I want to press the button to activate it

Comment: Ah right understood. I'll put in an answer with some code for you.

Answer (score 0):

So create a script similar to the rough psuedo code below and drop it onto the UI button.

```
public class ButtonHandler : MonoBehaviour
{
  private Button _button;
  void Awake() 
  {
    _button = GetComponent<Button>();
  }

  void Update() 
  {
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("x")) {
      _button.onClick.Invoke();
    }
  }
}
```

This will check for the button press (need to update that so it checks for the correct button) and then invoke the unity event that you already have assigned in the onClick() on the button.

Comment: Thanks!
Do I still have to put the onClick() event in the inspector in there?

Comment: Also the Input with the "GetButtonDown" wouldn't work for VR right? I thought of accessing the XR Input Actions with the primary button.